# Docker compose file not working for Sequlize and Mysql in Node app

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, sequelize.js

I have a Node js app build with express and sequelize .My database is Mysql.
I am using docker for make container from this app.I just used docker compose for Node and Mysql.

Here is my database config file for sequlize

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sample_db', 'root', '123456', {
    host: 'mysql',
    dialect: 'mysql',
  })


  sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('DB connected');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });


var db = {};

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  app: 
    container_name: my_app
    build: .
    ports: 
        - 5000:3000
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    expose:
        - "5000"
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
        - MYSQL_DB=sample_db
    ports:
        - "3307:3306"
```

But sequelize is not connected properly and gives the following error

```
SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:3306  at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:116:17)
```

Cant fix it. Is there a better way?

Comment: This may be a syncing issue. MySql may not be ready for connection when the app is ready to connect. Can you test this? (you can use `setTimeout` in the app)

Comment: The default user is root@'localhost'. the mysql-container is bound to your network interface port, meaning you can connect to it (test with `docker exec -it <cont-name-or-id> mysql -uroot -p123456`) because the database thinks you are connecting from "localhost", but your app is a different story. So you either grant remote access (like `GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; ` or you need to make some docker networks shenannigans. Maybe you can use `network_mode: "host"` on your app (and be forced to remove the port mapping)